# Custom directive not outputting correct result

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following custom directive `customerDirective` :

```
var app = angular.module('directiveApp', []);

var dirController = app.controller('DirectiveController', function() {
    this.customer = {
        name: 'James',
        address: 'Mellieha'
    };
});

dirController.directive('customerDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Name: {{customer.name}}      Address: {{customer.address}}'
    };
});
```

And I invoked it in `index.html` as follows :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-example12-production</title>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="directive.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="directiveApp">
    <div ng-controller="DirectiveController">
        <div customer-directive></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However the result outputted is not as expected:

```
Name:      Address:
```

For some reason, the angular expressions containing the customer details are not being captured. I resigned to the fact that I am probably overlooking something very obvious but alas I have not managed so far.

**PS: This example is taken directly from the AngularJS Developer Guide particularly from [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) section**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to solve this:

Example with $scope:

```js
var app = angular.module('directiveApp', []);

app.controller('DirectiveController', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'James',
        address: 'Mellieha'
    };
});

app.directive('customerDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Name: {{customer.name}}      Address: {{customer.address}}'
    };
});
```

Example with controller-as (without $scope):

```js
app.controller('DirectiveController', function() {
    this.customer = {
        name: 'James',
        address: 'Mellieha'
    };
});

app.directive('customerDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Name: {{dirCtrl.customer.name}}      Address: {{dirCtrl.customer.address}}'
    };
});

<body ng-app="directiveApp">
    <div ng-controller="DirectiveController as dirCtrl">
        <div customer-directive></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If use " dirController " variable to create directive, It's working. but u said right way to created controller and directive.

Comment: Do I HAVE to use `$scope` though? I thought using `this` instead is considered as best practice...

Comment: No you don´t have. You can also use the controller-as sytax. I will edit my post

Comment: Ah right okay so I had to refer the controller within the specification of the directive!

Comment: Also, why should I add the directive to the module and not to the controller? (Attaching it to the controller still works)

Comment: I never that it this way and thought it could be a potential trouble maker. But i just tested it inside a plunker and these two (app and dirController) are equal so it makes no difference, you can use both

Answer (score 0):

If you change this -- > $scope its working

```
var app = angular.module('directiveApp', []);
var dirController = app.controller('DirectiveController', function($scope) {
// Here Change         
$scope.customer = {
            name: 'James',
        address: 'Mellieha'
    };
});

dirController.directive('customerDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Name: {{customer.name}}      Address: {{customer.address}}'
    };
});
```